# Object recognition for coin ( from different views)

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection

I want to recognize a coin from different viewpoints which means I need to detect ellipse object. How I can do that specially with the different luminance for the coin ?
Who can help me with clear steps?

Example Image:
http://www.wallpapermania.eu/images/lthumbs/2013-04/4730_Coins-and-bills-money-everywere.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you choose any programming language?

Comment: Reposting @curiousgina's question as a comment: "Any progress with this idea? I would like to try something similar."

Answer (score 0):

If you can add some example images, it would be great and easier to answer.

If the background is different then the coin, you can use simple thresholding to detect the coin.

Detecting circular objects can also be done using the Hough transform.

**EDIT**: After looking at the image, I would suggest using the Hough transform for detecting circles.

Comment: Yes the background is different and the coin may not look like exact circle because of the viewpoint. I am having a problem detecting the coin in the image that has few other objects because the luminance's changes. What could help in that ?

Comment: I submit a URL of image because I need 10 reputation to submit one.

Comment: Having looked at your images, I suggest using the hough transform to detect circles.